# C# Serial communication custom function with AutoResetEvent timing out after first call

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication, autoresetevent

I'm trying to use serial communication to talk to a piece of custom hardware. The hardware has built in methods which can be called with a command.

To send a command and read the output of the function (from the hardware) I am using the `AutoResetEvent` event as shown below:

```
private string receiveMessage(string command)
{
    string rxMessage = "Error";

    var mre = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();

    serialPort.DataReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        buffer.Append(serialPort.ReadExisting());
        if (buffer.ToString().IndexOf("\r\n") >= 0)
        {
            rxMessage = buffer.ToString();

            mre.Set();
            buffer.Clear();
        }
    };

    var responseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    try
    {
        serialPort.WriteLine(command);
        if (!mre.WaitOne(responseTimeout))
        {
            rxMessage = "Did not receive response";
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        rxMessage = "Write took longer than expected";
    }
    catch
    {
        rxMessage = "Failed to write to port";
    }

    return rxMessage;
}
```

This method functions perfectly on the first call. But, if it is called a second time, the serial port times out and the method returns "Did not receive a response".

Am I missing something or have I created the `receieveMessage()` method incorrectly?

Many thanks.

Comment: The first delegate is still registered but it signals a different reset event.

Comment: Maybe use a named delegate and deregister it after use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to not unregistering the event handler. So the second time you call `receiveMessage` you will have to different event handlers. The first one will read all the data and set its auto-reset event. By the time the second event handler is called there is no data to read, and its auto-reset event will timeout.

To fix this you have a few alternatives. One is to unregister the event handler. To do this you need to either convert the lambda into a delegate object, i.e.

```
SerialDataReceivedEventHandler myHandler = (s, e) => {...}
 serialPort.DataReceived += myHandler ;
...
serialPort.DataReceived -= myHandler ;
```

Or replace your lambda with a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions).

Another alternative would be to change your method to a class, so that you only ever register the DateReceived event once.

Note that I think you have a race condition. If the data is received before `WaitOne` is called the event will not be set, and you will timeout. Using a ManualResetEvent/[ManualResetEventSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim?view=net-8.0) that keeps it signal state until explicitly reset should avoid this issue.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I used the first solution you suggested - I unregistered the event handler by turning the delegate into an object. Many thanks.